# When Firestore sets max concurrent connections, does that mean *active*?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

When Firestore sets max concurrent connections, does that mean *active*, in other words connections which are actively moving data, or does it mean the number of concurrent *subscriptions*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referring to the number of open client socket connections. This is not the same as the total number of listeners on documents and queries, since each client only opens a single socket, and pipelines data across that single socket.  Also bear in mind that each active client app process may not have an active socket connection open at any given time - the connection could come and go as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Per Firebase docs: A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database.

From this we can see it's not based on the data at all but rather where the connections are coming from.

Docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Comment: The documentation you linked is for the Firebase Realtime Database, while the question is about Cloud Firestore. While I think your conclusion is correct (it's per device/app instance), the documentation you linked is not a good source for that conclusion.